# Penalties on importing whole library in child module angular 2

Tags: angular

For example, if there is a big library with a lot of modules inside it and I use the whole library in the application (so size doesn't matter). But when I create child module and I need only 2 modules from that library, will be there any penalty if I include the whole library (if I already imported it in the main module)?

- Any performance penalties( the library is an npm module or a part of the project).
- It's included in the main module(original).
- And if it's isolated as I understand the penalty will be at least size.

Comment: Whats the relationship between your child module and the library module? And what are you referring to when you say penalty?

Comment: Any performance penalties( the library is an npm module or a part of the project). It's included in the main module(original). And if it's isolated as I understand the penalty will be at least size.